# Prove that $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2^e}$ is solvable $\forall e$ iff $a \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2^e}$ is solvable $\forall e$ iff $a \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$.

Whenever I encounter congruence proof, I'm stuck right away. How can I link $a \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ with the $a$ in the quadratic congruence equation? The only thing that I know from the top of my head is, to express $a = 8k + 1$, then plug it into the congruence equation to get $x^2 \equiv 8k + 1 \pmod{2^e}$. I still can't see anything from here. I feel like I don't know exactly what do I need to show. Can anyone lecture me on this? Quadratic residue is so confusing, I really can't see its practical purpose.

Thank you

Comment: You want Hensel's lemma: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel's_lemma

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Is there any other easier method? Thank you.

Comment: You can imitate the proof of Hensel's lemma in this special case. Hensel's lemma is not a particularly difficult method.

Comment: The statement of the result is not quite correct. Presumably you want to assume that $a$ is odd. Note since that the congruence $x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2^e}$ is always solvable, as is $x^2 \equiv 4$.

Comment: for all e? if I expand $x^2 \cong 8k+1(mod 2^e)$ to $x^2 = 2^em + 8k + 1$ and for all e means it should work when e=1 and x=6 which comes out to say 35 is a multiple of 2? or am I making an error here?

Comment: @Kate The problem is that you're picking a particular value for $x$ for which it does not work. The problem is just saying that the congruence is solvable, or that it has some solution, not that it works for all values of $x$.

Comment: ahh, right. so for all e there exists and x. thanks for helping clarify.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Hensel's Lemma require integer coefficient $k > 2$, so how can I use this lemma in this case because $x^2 \equiv a$ means $k = 1$? Please correct me if I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Chan: you have not used the fact that the equation must be solvable for all $e$.

Comment: @Quiaochu Yuan: But the `iff` means two directions, right? By that I meant, eventually we have to show that "If $a \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ then $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{2^e}$ is solvable for all $e$", don't we?

Comment: It might be worth looking at $(8k+1)^2$, $(8k+3)^2$, $(8k+5)^2$ and $(8k+7)^2$ $\mod 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, \text{ and } 64$ to see if you can spot a pattern.  As user6312 says, there are counterexamples if $a$ is even.

Answer (score 4):

The statement is obviously not correct when $a$ is even.
So we assume that $a$ is odd.

Since "only if" part is trivial, we prove "if" part.

Suppose $a \equiv 1$ (mod $8$)

Since $a \equiv 1$  (mod $2$) and $a \equiv 1$  (mod $4$), $x^2 \equiv a$ (mod $2^e$) has a solution when $e \leq 3$.

Let $k \geq 3$.
Suppose $x^2 \equiv a$ (mod $2^k$) has a solution $x_0$.
It suffices to prove that $x^2 \equiv a$ (mod $2^{k+1}$) has a solution $y_0$.

Let $y_0 = x_0 + 2^{k-1}t$.
We determine t such that $y_0^2 \equiv a$ (mod $2^{k+1}$).
$y_0^2 \equiv x_0^2 + 2^k tx_0$ (mod $2^{k+1}$).
Hence  $y_0^2 - a \equiv x_0^2 -a + 2^k tx_0$ (mod $2^{k+1}$).
It suffices to solve $x_0^2 - a + 2^k tx_0 \equiv 0$ (mod $2^{k+1}$).
Since $x_0^2 \equiv a$ (mod $2^k$), $x_0^2 - a = 2^k c$ for some integer c.
Hence $2^k c + 2^k tx_0 \equiv 0$ (mod $2^{k+1}$).
Hence $c+ tx_0 \equiv 0$ (mod $2$).
Since $x_0$ is odd, this has a solution $t$.
Hence we are done.